# I believe this to be a (minor) defect in the C++11 Standard

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I believe this to be a (minor) defect in the C++11 Standard. In [dcl.dcl] we have:

> *simple-declaration*:
>
> *decl-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* *init-declarator-list<sub>opt</sub>* **;**

The *decl-specifier-seq* can't be optional.

For instance the snippet below doesn't compile:

```
x;
```

If I'm correct here, then the beginning of paragraph §8.3/1 should also be altered:

From:

> A list of declarators appears after an optional (Clause 7)
> *decl-specifier-seq* (7.1).

To:

> A list of declarators appears after a *decl-specifier-seq* (7.1).

Comment: Since we're not in a position to change the standard, what do you want us to do about this?

Comment: @MikeW I may be wrong.

Comment: Who is close-voting this as primarily opinion-based?

Comment: BTW, the grammar isn't meant to be exact: "_This summary of C ++ syntax is intended to be an aid to comprehension. It is not an exact statement of the language. In particular, the grammar described here accepts a superset of valid C ++ constructs._" (Annex A)

Comment: The obviously implicit question here is "Am I correct?".  Don't be so pedantic.

Comment: There is a thin line between syntax and semantic constraints. As long as the standard is clear about what is or is not allowed, it doesn't really matter if it is handled by the grammar directly or by a separate semantic processing phase.

Comment: Perhaps this question would be better received if presented as asking "When does a *simple-declaration* not need a *decl-specifier-seq*?"

Comment: @remyable I'm curious to know how did you get those `opt`s in subscript?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil The `<sub>` tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Too long for a comment

In clause 7, paragraph 3:

> **In a *simple-declaration*, the optional *init-declarator-list* can be
>   omitted only when declaring a class (Clause 9) or enumeration (7.2),
>   that is, when the *decl-specifier-seq* contains either a
>   *class-specifier*, an *elaborated-type-specifier* with a *class-key* (9.1),
>   or an *enum-specifier*.** In these cases and whenever a *class-specifier* or
>   *enum-specifier* is present in the *decl-specifier-seq*, the identifiers
>   in these specifiers are among the names being declared by the
>   declaration (as *class-names*, *enum-names*, or *enumerators*, depending on
>   the syntax). In such cases, and except for the declaration of an
>   unnamed bit-field (9.6), the *decl-specifier-seq* shall introduce one or
>   more names into the program, or shall redeclare a name introduced by a
>   previous declaration.

And in clause 7, paragraph 9

> **Only in function declarations for constructors, destructors, and type
>   conversions can the *decl-specifier-seq* be omitted.**

Comment: This is not saying anything about a missing type in a declaration.

Comment: @DieterLücking No, you bolded in which cases the *init-declarator-list* may be omitted, not in which cases the *decl-specifier-seq* may be omitted.

Comment: And footnote 89 says `The “implicit int” rule of C is no longer supported.`

Comment: That second part (but only that second part) looks like a correct answer to me. :)

Comment: I agree with @hvd. The second part seems to be the answer. The first part (paragraph 3) has nothing to do with it.